# Adding 2 pointers by overloaded operator+ causing infinite loop c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am writing my Arrayhandler class, and I need to overload `operator+` and `operator++`.

Is it a good idea to overload `operator++` by `operator+(1)`? I get an infinite loop because as far as I find out `_current = _pointee + i` (where `i` is size_t) does not change `_current`. Why? Is it right to add pointers in such a way?

```
class ArrayHandler
{
private:
     size_t _size;

     Pointee *_pointee; 
     Pointee *_end;
     mutable Pointee *_current; 
  ....
}
```

My Ctor:

```
template <typename Pointee>
    ArrayHandler<Pointee>::ArrayHandler(size_t size):
        _size(size), _pointee(new Pointee[_size]), _end(_pointee+_size), _current(_pointee)
        {};
```

Operator+ :

```
ArrayHandler<Pointee>& ArrayHandler<Pointee>::operator+(size_t i)
    {
        if (!defined())
            throw MisUse(undefArray, 0);
        if ( _pointee + i > _end || _pointee + i < _pointee)
            throw MisUse(badIndex, i);
        _current = _pointee + i;
        return *this;
    };
```

Operator++ :

```
template <typename Pointee>
ArrayHandler<Pointee>& ArrayHandler<Pointee>::operator++()
{
    if (!defined())
        throw MisUse(undefArray, 0);
    if ( stop() )
        throw MisUse(badIndex, 0);
    ++_current;*/
    this->operator+(1);
    return *this;
};
```

the while-loop that causes infinite execution:

```
while (!ar3.stop())
    {
        ++ar3;
        ++count;
    }
```

and the `stop()` method :

```
 bool stop() const {return _current ==_end;}
```

**UPDATE:**

The reason for infinite while loop was that I implemented operator++ by operator+, which, in my case, did change _current,  each time to start+1 , so after second iteration my _current remained unchanged. it was repeatedly RESET by start+1 each time.

GUYS!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your operator + you do not increase current, but reset it each time to start+i;

```
_current = _pointee + i;
```

You probably mean to do this:

```
_current = _current + i;
```

Comment: I see your point. No, actually I indeed wanted to _current = start + i,

Comment: Maybe I should correct myself, you probably should not change _current at all, because you only want to return a result which is added, but not change itself, otherwise it would be the operator +=. You now increase _current in operator++, and change it again in operator+.

Comment: actually I indeed wanted to `_current = start + i` , i think it looks more like real address arithmetic. `(ptr + 3)` changes `"_current"` regarding ptr, not `"current" = "current" +3`

Comment: It is just a really bad signature. It really should be +=

Comment: best answer! i finally got it :)

Answer (score 3):

You are making a mistake wrt operator overloading: Your `operator+` modifies its argument! Consider:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = a + b;
```

Would you expect that `a` is modified when you called `a + b`? Certainly not.

What you want to do is to implement `operator+=` properly and then provide an `operator+` and (if you want) an `operator++` (maybe both prefix ++i and postfix i++ versions) which internally use your `operator+=`. Here are some sketches for the latter which go *outside* of your class definition as free functions:

```
template <typename Pointee>
ArrayHandler<Pointee> operator+( ArrayHandler<Pointee> arg, size_t i )
{
    arg += i;
    return arg;
}

template <typename Pointee>
ArrayHandler<Pointee>& operator++( ArrayHandler<Pointee>& arg ) // prefix ++
{
    arg += 1;
    return arg;
}

template <typename Pointee>
ArrayHandler<Pointee> operator++( ArrayHandler<Pointee> arg, int ) // postfix ++
{
    arg += 1;
    return arg;
}
```

Now for `operator+=`, you could implement it like this (as a member function):

```
ArrayHandler<Pointee>& ArrayHandler<Pointee>::operator+=(size_t i)
{
    if (!defined())
        throw MisUse(undefArray, 0);
    if ( _current + i >= _end || _current + i < _pointee)
        throw MisUse(badIndex, i); // this message is now probably misleading
    _current += i;
    return *this;
};
```

This advances `_current` by `i` elements, which is the intended semantics of an `operator+=`. If you simply want to access the `i`-th element, you should consider writing `operator[]`.

You might also consider using helper libraries for the boiler-plate code, like Boost.Operators, see my profile for some links.

Comment: ok, the signature is wrong. still, the question remains : why calling `operator+(1)` from `operator++` CAUSE INFINITE WHILE loop? in my code,                                                          `ArrayHandler<Pointee>& ArrayHandler<Pointee>::operator+(size_t i)` **_current = _pointee + i;** does not change _current!

Comment: @Oleksandra I updated the answer, see if this works for you. And don't waste your time fixing your existing operators as this will never really do what it should. Fixing things as I proposed also helps to avoid bugs and write clearer code.